# Unable to create python dictionary is specific format

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3

I have the following data:

```
        response = {'connections': [{'ownerAccount': '11111111111', 'connectionId': 'dxcon-ff', 'region': 'eu-west-1'},
                                    {'ownerAccount': '11111111111', 'connectionId': 'dxcon-pl', 'region': 'eu-west-2'},
                                    {'ownerAccount': '11111111111', 'connectionId': 'dxcon-123', 'region': 'eu-west-2'},
                                    {'ownerAccount': '222222222222', 'connectionId': 'dxcon-51', 'region': 'us-east-1'},
                                    {'ownerAccount': '222222222222', 'connectionId': 'dxcon-1i', 'region': 'us-east-2'},
                                    {'ownerAccount': '333333333333', 'connectionId': 'dxcon-511i', 'region': 'eu-west-1'}]}
```

I want to create a map of accounts something like this

```
        a = {
            "11111111111" = {"eu-west-1": ["dxcon-ff"], "eu-west-2": ["dxcon-pl", "dxcon-123"]},
            "222222222222" = {"us-east-1": ["dxcon-51"], "us-east-2": ["dxcon-1i"]},
            "333333333333" = {"eu-west-1": ["dxcon-511i"]}
        }
```

Such that if I do `a['11111111111']['eu-west-1']` output should be `["dxcon-ff"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job,

```
mydict = {}

for connection in response["connections"]:
  owner = connection["ownerAccount"]
  if owner not in mydict:
    mydict[owner] = {}
    
  mydict[owner][connection["region"]] = []
  mydict[owner][connection["region"]].append(connection["connectionId"])

print(mydict)
```

Output -

```
{'11111111111': {'eu-west-1': ['dxcon-ff'], 'eu-west-2': ['dxcon-123']},
 '222222222222': {'us-east-1': ['dxcon-51'], 'us-east-2': ['dxcon-1i']},
 '333333333333': {'eu-west-1': ['dxcon-511i']}}
```

Comment: Your mydict['11111111111']['eu-west-2'] is wrong, shouldn't make an empty list before appending element in it in every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data = {'connections': [
    {'ownerAccount': '11111111111', 'connectionId': 'dxcon-ff', 'region': 'eu-west-1'},
    {'ownerAccount': '11111111111', 'connectionId': 'dxcon-pl', 'region': 'eu-west-2'},
    {'ownerAccount': '11111111111', 'connectionId': 'dxcon-123', 'region': 'eu-west-2'},
    {'ownerAccount': '222222222222', 'connectionId': 'dxcon-51', 'region': 'us-east-1'},
    {'ownerAccount': '222222222222', 'connectionId': 'dxcon-1i', 'region': 'us-east-2'},
    {'ownerAccount': '333333333333', 'connectionId': 'dxcon-511i', 'region': 'eu-west-1'}]}
                                    
a = {}
for d in data['connections']:
    key = d['ownerAccount']
    region = d['region']
    conId = d['connectionId']
    if key not in a.keys():
        a[key] = {}
    if region not in a[key].keys():
        a[key][region]= []
    a[key][region].append(conId)

print(a)
print(a['11111111111']['eu-west-1'])
```

Result:

```
{
    '11111111111': {'eu-west-1': ['dxcon-ff'], 'eu-west-2': ['dxcon-pl', 'dxcon-123']}, 
    '222222222222': {'us-east-1': ['dxcon-51'], 'us-east-2': ['dxcon-1i']}, 
    '333333333333': {'eu-west-1': ['dxcon-511i']}
}
['dxcon-ff']
```